# Syntax for && operator with jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax, operator-keyword

I have 2 radio buttons that I want to throw a validation if both are unchecked. I'm sure my syntax is wrong somewhere and would appreciate help with this, and if there is a better way to do it.
Thanks.

 
My js fiddle link: [http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/THQj2/18/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed (

```
 if( (  !$('#radio1').attr('checked')===true) && 
 ----^                      (!$('#radio2').attr('checked'))===true) {
```

and you have to add return false also

```
$('#validate').show();
 return false;
```

Final code

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if((!$('#radio1').attr('checked')===true) && (!$('#radio2').attr
                                                       ('checked'))===true) { 
    $('#validate').show();
     return false;
    }else{
       $('#validate').hide();
    }

});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/THQj2/28/)

Comment: You all rock. Thanks for all the iterations. Got it now. :D

Answer (score 1):

you are making it to look complex - you can just do this

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$('#radio1').prop('checked') && !$('#radio2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#validate').show();
    }
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/THQj2/33/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong (missing `(` ) .
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntm6N/2/) with the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra bracket after first true .. it should be like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if(!$('#radio1').attr('checked')===true && (!$('#radio2').attr('checked'))===true) { 
        $('#validate').show();
    }  
});
```

Updated jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/THQj2/31/

Answer (score 0):

Correct!

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if((!$('#radio1').attr('checked')===true) && (!$('#radio2').attr('checked'))===true) { 
  $('#validate').show();
}

});
```